# Unity struggle making endless runner game 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am trying to build an endless runner gane in Unity Engine and I keep getting this error message. 
The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class obsticale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            //plaer takes damage!
            other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typos.

Should be `other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")`

There is multiple other typos below that.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))) 
    {
        //player takes damage!
        player = other.gameObject;

        player.GetComponent<yourscriptname>().health -= damage;

        Debug.Log(player.GetComponent<yourscriptname>().health);

        Destroy(player);
    }
```

Edit: Also I understand you are new, however I believe people would rather you put your code inside the designated code blocks on the website to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Where is the code block. I dont know where is it. I'm using the app.